# Is there any way of making queries that contain special characters like 'ã' in spatialite-gui?

Tags: error, linux, spatialite-gui

I have a Spatialite database file that has some special characters inside their columns as the following:

[image]

Here there's the word "Itapoã"... The problem is that all the times that I try to type this character in a query, spatialite-gui crashes:

[image]

The error that I see is:

```
An assertion failed!

../src/common/unichar.cpp(65): assert "Assert failure" failed in ToHi8bit(): character cannot be converted to single byte
```

I haven't found any relevant information googling this error... I know that the query works if I open the command line interface for Spatialite. The problem here is only with spatialite-gui... Is there any workaround for this kind of problem? Or I should probably just accept that inside spatialite-gui I won't be able to use special characters like 'â'?

OBS: just copying and pasting the character to the spatialite-gui interface should be enough to reproduce the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with spatialite-gui (SpatiaLite 5.0.0) on Windows.

[image]

Comment: It must be a Linux problem then... Both on `Ubuntu 18.04` with the SpatiaLite version 4.3.0a and `Ubuntu 20.04` with the SpatiaLite version 5.0.0 are crashing with the same error here.

Comment: Create a smallest possible database that shows the problem to be linked with the message to users group https://groups.google.com/g/spatialite-users.